# i am searching for a that collect the text from web site and write it in to a single text file

Tags: perl

i am searching for a perl script that takes website address as a input and collect the total text from given website and written to a single text file. so please do help me.
following is have currently

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n";
use CGI;
use Cwd;
$q=new CGI;
$a=$q->param('file');
chomp($a);
my $ftpname="$a";
system("wget --mirror -p --convert-links -x --reject=gif $ftpname");
```

Comment: The script you posted looks like it should work for collecting text in files. What happens when you try to run it, and what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/libwww-perl/lib/LWP.pm) or specifically at [LWP::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/libwww-perl-6.05/lib/LWP/UserAgent.pm). You can then write the received data to a file.